# overleaf shortcut keys not working

Tags: overleaf, shortcut

I was using overleaf for a long time and now since I changed the laptop and the OS to windows 11 shortcuts are not working anymore like `ctr+b` `ctrl+f` even the `Backspace` key is not working anymore and this is only on overleaf its ok on other sites

- I tried to add shift and it does not resolve the problem
- Keybindings is set to None

Comment: Overleaf-specific questions should be directed to the Overleaf Helpdesk. Their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: @Mico I'm waiting for their answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think so, their is two over options Vim and Emacs and truly i don't know what they are for

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the Backspace is working again with Emacs but not for the others like ctrl + b for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the TeX Live version to 2021 and it works for me